# update all rows at once with different where condition my sql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table name details in which there are two columns. First one is name and second is gender. The table consist around 50 entries of names and gender male/female. I am trying to update the gender column which contains male and female both according to person gender. What I want to do is change the data where gender = male to female and female to male

Here's the query I've tried:

```
UPDATE details 
SET    gender = 'm', 
       gender='f' 
WHERE  gender = 'm';
```

Comment: i tried one where condition but it changes all to female.

Comment: update details set gender = 'm', gender='f' where gender = 'm';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it to be in one statement, try using a `CASE` statement instead:

```
UPDATE  Details 
SET     Gender = CASE WHEN Gender = 'm' THEN 'f' ELSE 'm' END 
WHERE   Gender IN ('m', 'f')
```